# Xtext Creating verbose error messages for expressions: how to get the rule trace on a syntax error?

Tags: antlr, xtext

I am attempting to extend a SyntaxErrorMessageProvider in order to override the syntax error messages however I don't know how to get the stack trace of the rules which invoked this syntax error:

```
class MySyntaxErrorMessageProvider extends SyntaxErrorMessageProvider {
    def override SyntaxErrorMessage getSyntaxErrorMessage(ISyntaxErrorMessageProvider.IParserErrorContext context) {
        if(context.recognitionException != null) {
            handle(context.recognitionException)
        } else {
            handleException(context)
        }
```

What I would like to achieve is for instance when given the following text:

```
1. 1 +

2. 1 + +

3. 1 1

4. 1 1 +
```

The error messages should be and give the following quickfix options:

```
1. 1 + is an incomplete expression, mainly + has no right hand operand

2. 1 + + is an incomplete expression, mainly 1 + in (1 +) + has no right operand or expression and + in 1 + (+) has no left or right operands or expressions
```

The quickfixes for these options could be (Addition or Removal):

```
1. Remove the + or Add in an expression

2. Add in an operand/expression for both ends of + or remove leftmost token.
```

I am struggling to find a way to do this using the Xtext api. I have gotten the INode of the incorrect parse but what I'm getting from these nodes is not the complete input as I walk the tree using the .getAsTreeIterable(). It is only showing the text which would be valid in the model.

1. Would I have to add in some error rules to the grammar that would capture these incorrect cases just to be able to identify them using the INode interface?
2. Input:

   badinput = 1 + 2 + +

I get the following nodes:

```
Start....

Defsym_exprImpl@153802c5 (defSymbolName: badinput)

AdditionImpl@1dc74ee0

AdditionImpl@2335d787

INTEGER_CONSTANTImpl@19816081 (value: 1)

INTEGER_CONSTANTImpl@4cfa675e (value: 2)

UNARY_PLUSImpl@6bed906f

End....
```

of which I could iterate through them and check whether some of their corresponding values are Null, would this be the right way forward?

Does anyone have any more suggestions to offer?

The grammar for my implementation is below:

```
    Expression returns Expression:
    Assignment
;

Assignment returns Expression:
    Ternary (
            ( ({AndEquals.left=current} AND EQUALS)
            | ({OrEquals.left=current} OR EQUALS)
            | ({PlusEquals.left=current} PLUS EQUALS)
            | ({MinusEquals.left=current} MINUS EQUALS)
            | ({MultiplyEquals.left=current} MULTIPLY EQUALS)
            | ({DivideEquals.left=current} DIVIDE EQUALS)
            | ({Equals.left=current} EQUALS)
            | ({LeftShiftEquals.left=current} LEFT_SHIFT EQUALS)
            | ({RightShiftEquals.left=current} RIGHT_SHIFT EQUALS)
            )
        right=Ternary
    )*
;

Ternary returns Expression:
     OrOr ({Ternar.left=current} SEMICOLON rightTrue=OrOr QUESTION rightFalse=OrOr)*
;

OrOr returns Expression:
    AndAnd ({OrOr.left=current} OR_OR right=AndAnd)*
;

AndAnd returns Expression:
    BitwiseOr ({AndAnd.left=current} AND_AND right=BitwiseOr)*
;

BitwiseOr returns Expression:
    BitwiseXOR ({Or.left=current} OR right=BitwiseXOR)*
;

BitwiseXOR returns Expression:
    BitwiseAnd ({XOr.left=current} XOR right=BitwiseAnd)*
;

BitwiseAnd returns Expression:
    Comparisons ({And.left=current} AND right=Comparisons)*
;

Comparisons returns Expression:
    Shifting (( ( {EqualsEquals.left=current} EQUALS_EQUALS) 
             | ( {NotEquals.left=current} NOT_EQUALS)
             | ( {GreaterThan.left=current} GREATER_THAN)
             | ( {LessThan.left=current} LESS_THAN)
             | ( {LessThanEquals.left=current} LESS_THAN_EQUALS)
             | ( {GreaterEquals.left=current} GREATER_EQUALS)
             )
             right=Shifting
    )*
;

Shifting returns Expression:
    AdditionOrSubtraction (  ( {LeftShift.left=current} LEFT_SHIFT 
                             | {RightShift.left=current} RIGHT_SHIFT
                             ) right=AdditionOrSubtraction)*
;

AdditionOrSubtraction returns Expression:
    MultiplicationOrDivision (   ( {Addition.left=current} PLUS 
                                 | {Subtraction.left=current} MINUS
                               ) (right=MultiplicationOrDivision))*
;

MultiplicationOrDivision returns Expression: 
    UnaryOperations ( ( {Multiplication.left=current} MULTIPLY 
                      | {Division.left=current} DIVIDE 
                      | {Modulus.left=current} MOD
                      ) right=UnaryOperations)*
;

UnaryOperations returns Expression:
    ({UNARY_MINUS} MINUS value=UnaryOperations)
    /* +(1 + 2) is not supported in the original LD*/
    | ({UNARY_PLUS} PLUS value=UnaryOperations)
    | ({UNARY_BITWISE_NOT} BITWISE_NOT value=UnaryOperations)
    | ({UNARY_LOGICAL_NOT} LOGICAL_NOT value=UnaryOperations)
    | Primary
;

Primary returns Expression:
    RecursiveExpressions
    | AtomicExpressions
    | Constants
    | Atom
;

RecursiveExpressions returns Expression:
    OPEN_BRACKET Expression CLOSE_BRACKET
    | {NEXT_BUILT_IN} NEXT OPEN_BRACKET value=Expression CLOSE_BRACKET
    | {LOG2CEIL_BUILT_IN} LOG2CEIL OPEN_BRACKET value=Expression CLOSE_BRACKET
    | {ABSOLUTE_BUILT_IN} ABSOLUTE OPEN_BRACKET value=Expression CLOSE_BRACKET
    | {ALIGN_BUILT_IN} ALIGN OPEN_BRACKET left=Expression (COMMA right=Expression)? CLOSE_BRACKET
    | {SEGMENT_ALIGN_BUILT_IN} DATA_SEGMENT_ALIGN OPEN_BRACKET left=Expression COMMA right=Expression CLOSE_BRACKET
    | {SEGMENT_RELRO_END_BUILT_IN} DATA_SEGMENT_RELRO_END OPEN_BRACKET left=Expression COMMA right=Expression CLOSE_BRACKET
    | {SEGMENT_BUILT_IN} DATA_SEGMENT_END OPEN_BRACKET value=Expression CLOSE_BRACKET
    | {START_BUILT_IN} SEGMENT_START OPEN_BRACKET name=ID COMMA value=Expression CLOSE_BRACKET
    | {BLOCK_BUILT_IN} BLOCK OPEN_BRACKET value=Expression CLOSE_BRACKET
    | {MAX_DOUBLE_BUILT_IN} MAX OPEN_BRACKET left=Expression COMMA right=Expression CLOSE_BRACKET
    | {MIN_DOUBLE_BUILT_IN} MIN OPEN_BRACKET left=Expression COMMA right=Expression CLOSE_BRACKET
    | {ASSERT_E_BUILT_IN} ASSERT OPEN_BRACKET value=Expression COMMA name=ID CLOSE_BRACKET
;

Constants returns Expression:
    /* Constants */
    {COUNTER} LOCATION_COUNTER
    | {SIZE_OF_HEADER} SIZEOF_HEADERS   
;

AtomicExpressions returns Expression:
    {ATOMIC_DEFINED} DEFINED OPEN_BRACKET value=ID CLOSE_BRACKET
    | {ATOMIC_ALIGN_OF} ALIGN_OF OPEN_BRACKET value=ID CLOSE_BRACKET
    | {ATOMIC_SIZE_OF} SIZEOF OPEN_BRACKET value=ID CLOSE_BRACKET
    | {ATOMIC_ADDR} ADDR OPEN_BRACKET value=ID CLOSE_BRACKET
    | {ATOMIC_LOAD_ADDR} LOADADDR OPEN_BRACKET value=ID CLOSE_BRACKET
    | {ATOMIC_CONSTANT} CONSTANT OPEN_BRACKET value=ID CLOSE_BRACKET
    | {ATOMIC_ORIGIN} ORIGIN OPEN_BRACKET value=ID CLOSE_BRACKET
    | {ATOMIC_LENGTH} LENGTH OPEN_BRACKET value=ID CLOSE_BRACKET    
;

Atom returns Expression:
    {INTEGER_CONSTANT} value=INT
;
```

Would I need to add in rules such as the following?

```
1. 1 +

2. 1 + +

3. 1 1

4. 1 1 +
```

Case 1 could be handled by the direct AST

For Case 2:

```
Operators:
   '+' | '-' | '*' | '/' etc...;

AdditionOrSubtraction returns Expression:
    MultiplicationOrDivision (   ( {Addition.left=current} PLUS 
                                 | {Subtraction.left=current} MINUS
                                 ) 
                                 (right=MultiplicationOrDivision)
                                 | Operators  /* however how do I flag/paraphrase this to be of type Error of some sort? this may also be ambiguous grammar */
                             )*
;
```

For Case 3 I dont know that seems hard aswell as case 4.

Comment: For my better understanding: You want to iterate upwards your AST to find any node not containing an element which should contain an element?

Comment: @Joko I think that's one of the aspects, however the input may not always be captured in the way I imagine them to be, which is why im thinking maybe the AST isnt what I want. i.e.the last '+' in 1 + + + comes out to be a unary-plus whereas I would assume it is a binary +. Which makes me feels more natural to use a stack trace of a parser (which I dont think I have) but im not sure.

Comment: I have only worked with the AST in Xtext to solve any problems, not with any Exceptions ... Do you use your completely own grammar or do you reuse any Xbase rules?

Comment: @Joko its all my grammar no rules from Xbase

Comment: Ok, maybe it is helpful to post your grammar. If you add comments to the rules which are involved in your problem, it could help to better understand your problem.

Comment: @Joko good idea, ill do that when I get the chance

Answer (score 1):

have a look at the fields `node` and `token` of the `RecognitionException`

Comment: my node is always null. I am currently checking the EObject type to determine if it is an expression, however I am not 100% sure if this is right.

Comment: i guess it depends on the situation of the error if and which fields are filled